# Can't use if condition in JavaScripts (userscript)

Tags: javascript, regex, if-statement

I feel dumb for that question. I know how use `if` condition in bash and there are some differences that ruins my code. In bash you can write `*` character to show not care what there writen,`^` for protocol and `=~` for approximately equal. Example:

```
url = https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solovetsky_Stone
if [[ $url =~ ^.*.wikipedia.org/wiki/* ]]
```

It find all wiki page in any language and in mobile mode or not. I don't know how do that in javascript. I can't use `string1.localeCompare(string2)` because it show only same (0) and a in b and b in a (1,-1).
I want run script in specific page via comparing url in userscript (javascript).

Sorry for my english.

Comment: try to use regex and patterns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're thinking of in bash is regular expression matching. You can do that in JavaScript as well with [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) and [String.prototype.match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match).

In the case of your example, the `if` statement would be:

```js
const url = 'https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solovetsky_Stone'
if (url.match(/^.*.wikipedia.org\/wiki\/*/)) {
  console.log('wikipedia article');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean a [regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

```js
const url = "https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solovetsky_Stone"
if (/^.*\.wikipedia.org\/wiki\/.*/.test(url)) {
  console.log("Yes it is WIKI")
}
```

Comment: Can I use `var` instead `const`? Because in my userscript there is varible list that created before script

Comment: Sure. Const, var, let